# query get the current date with condition

Tags: sql, date, db2, datediff

I need to get the date from date table minus 3 days (business days to be specific). Below is the structure:

```
      date           business day
      1/1/13         Y  
      1/2/13         N
      1/3/13         Y
      1/4/13         Y
      1/5/13         Y
```

Suppose if `todays` date is `1/5/13` then I need to get `current_date - 3`(business)days which is `1/1/13` (since 1/2/13 is a non - business day)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with what is known as a 'windowing' function.  The following should work on all (recent) versions of DB2 (untested, though, as I'm away from my instance):

```
SELECT calendar_date
FROM (SELECT calendar_date, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY calendar_date DESC) as rownum
      FROM Calendar
      WHERE calendar_date < CURRENT_DATE
            AND business_day = 'Y') c
WHERE ROW_NUM = 3
```

Which should result in `2013-01-01`.

If you are doing a lot of similar math, I'd actually recommend creating stored procedures for this sort of thing, say something like `addBusinessDays(calendar_date, days_to_add)`.  Although you have to access a table for it to work, you should be able to mark it as `DETERMINISTIC` (well, assuming the compiler lets you get away with that, and that days aren't suddenly switched...)

Answer (score -1):

If it is MSSQL then you can use,

```
GETDATE() - 3
```

If it is MYSQL then you can check the date functions at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

I believe `CURDATE()` will work for MYSQL.

Answer (score -1):

I doubt if you can find a solution to this problem using only SQL. What you will need is some help to programmatically solve this (using stored procedures or similar).